# Pythonically Concatenating Two Similar but Highly Nested JSON Objects

Tags: python, json, replace, python-requests, generator

I have a huge JSON object of "people" records...like so--fetched via an API call using Requests:

```
{
    people: [
        { 
            foo: { key: value, ...},
            bar: { key: value, ...},
            person: { name: Harry, ...},
            baz: { key: value, ...}
        },
        { 
            foo: { key: value, ...},
            bar: { key: value, ...},
            person: { name: Sally, ...},
            baz: { key: value, ...}
        },
        {
            ... # many more records
        }
    ]
}
```

And a second call to the same API produces additional records that are formmatted and labeled exactly the same...

```
{
    people: [
        { 
            foo: { key: value, ...},
            bar: { key: value, ...},
            person: { name: Jack, ...},
            baz: { key: value, ...}
        },
        { 
            foo: { key: value, ...},
            bar: { key: value, ...},
            person: { name: Jill, ...},
            baz: { key: value, ...}
        },
        {
            ... #many more records
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to concatenate these records into one file (or, say, parse and manipulate the data for ultimate insertion into a database). I need to keep *all* records... I'm not seeking to overwrite any single record in the JSON object.

It's easy enough for me to append the second set of records to a file containing the first set...but I get:

```
{
    people: [
        { 
            foo: { key: value, ...},
            bar: { key: value, ...},
            person: { name: Harry, ...},
            baz: { key: value, ...}
        },
        { 
            foo: { key: value, ...},
            bar: { key: value, ...},
            person: { name: Sally, ...},
            baz: { key: value, ...}
        },
        {
            ... #many more records
        }
    ]
}
{
    people: [
        { 
            foo: { key: value, ...},
            bar: { key: value, ...},
            person: { name: Jack, ...},
            baz: { key: value, ...}
        },
        { 
            foo: { key: value, ...},
            bar: { key: value, ...},
            person: { name: Jill, ...},
            baz: { key: value, ...}
        },
        {
            ... #many more records
        }
    ]
}
```

...but these characters:

```
    ]
}
{
    people: [
```

...(plus a missing comma at the end of the last record in the first response) make it not valid JSON.

How can I properly concatenate these two JSON objects--i.e., write them to file as one big properly formatted and valid JSON object?

What's the most optimal way? I think it's best to strip the unwanted fields from the API responses *prior* to concatenating these two objects and writing them to file. But--if I just wanted to remove the unwanted characters once they *are* written to file...how would I do that, too?

I've tried .replace(), .strip(), contemplated using a regex, tried sticking the data into a list and using a list comprehension, tried a dictionary comprehension, and a few generators. Not totally certain what the best and most idiomatic course of action is...

Comment: But the code formated you gave isn't a valid JSON neither a valid Python dict.

Comment: have you tried [json.dump](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump)?

Comment: why are you not merging `people` lists into one?

Answer (score 1):

Your formated code isn't a valid Python dict neither a valid JSON.

But, if your data is like this format (see above) you can use `literal_eval` from `ast` module and convert your data into a valid `python dict` then you can dump it into a file or use it in you program.

See this example:

```
from ast import literal_eval as le

a = '''{
    'people': [
        { 
            'foo': { 'key': 'value'},
            'bar': { 'key': 'value'},
            'person': { 'name': 'Harry'},
            'baz': { 'key': 'value'}
        },
        { 
            'foo': { 'key': 'value'},
            'bar': { 'key': 'value'},
            'person': { 'name': 'Sally'},
            'baz': { 'key': 'value'}
        }]}'''

b = '''{
    'people': [
        { 
            'foo': { 'key': 'value'},
            'bar': { 'key': 'value'},
            'person': { 'name': 'Harry'},
            'baz': { 'key': 'value'}
        },
        { 
            'foo': { 'key': 'value'},
            'bar': { 'key': 'value'},
            'person': { 'name': 'Sally'},
            'baz': { 'key': 'value'}
        }]}'''



final = [le(a), le(b)]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[{'people': [{'person': {'name': 'Harry'}, 'baz': {'key': 'value'}, 'bar': {'key': 'value'}, 'foo': {'key': 'value'}}, {'person': {'name': 'Sally'}, 'baz': {'key': 'value'}, 'bar': {'key': 'value'}, 'foo': {'key': 'value'}}]}, {'people': [{'person': {'name': 'Harry'}, 'baz': {'key': 'value'}, 'bar': {'key': 'value'}, 'foo': {'key': 'value'}}, {'person': {'name': 'Sally'}, 'baz': {'key': 'value'}, 'bar': {'key': 'value'}, 'foo': {'key': 'value'}}]}]
```